# How to have different callback signature depending on other parameter types?

Tags: typescript

I am playing with typescript at the moment and have difficulties grasping how to overload a function, that is accepting a callback.

My function is a wrapper around a canvas element. It should accept up to 2 parameters:

1. A callback, that accepts a rendering context
2. An optional object, where you can define the context to be returned. It has a `type` and an `attributes` property, based on the canvas' [getContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) method.

Now depending on the value of the `type` property, I want the callback signature to be different. If the value is '2d' or it is omitted, then it should be `(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => void`, if the value is 'webgl2', then it should be `(context: WebGL2RenderingContext) => void` and so on.

The problem is now, that I do not want to have `(context: any) => void` as my callback signature in the actual implementation (my linter prohibits this). How would I need to define this signature, to obtain my desired result?

You can see my try below, but it gives me the error:

> Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.

```
function useCanvas(
  draw: (context: WebGLRenderingContext) => void,
  options: { type: 'webgl' | 'experimental-webgl'; attributes?: WebGLContextAttributes },
): React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>;
function useCanvas(
  draw: (context: WebGL2RenderingContext) => void,
  options: { type: 'webgl2'; attributes?: WebGLContextAttributes },
): React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>;
function useCanvas(
  draw: (context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => void,
  options?: { type?: '2d'; attributes?: CanvasRenderingContext2DSettings },
): React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>;
function useCanvas(
  draw: (
    context: CanvasRenderingContext2D | WebGLRenderingContext | WebGL2RenderingContext,
  ) => void,
  {
    type = '2d',
    attributes,
  }: {
    type?: '2d' | 'webgl' | 'experimental-webgl' | 'webgl2';
    attributes?: CanvasRenderingContext2DSettings | WebGLContextAttributes;
  } = {},
): React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement> {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current !== null) {
      ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext(type, attributes);

      draw(ctx);
    }
  });

  return canvasRef;
}
```

The idea is, that typescript can interfere what the callbacks argument is, when you write it. Then it would be impossible to use methods on a 2D context, that just exist on WebGL and vice versa.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that TypeScript doesn't unify a union of functions into a function of an argument that is a union.

Another issue that the definition of `getContext` in standard library does not distinguish different types, which we can fix by augmenting that interface:

```
interface HTMLCanvasElement {
  getContext(
    contextId: '2d', attributes?: CanvasRenderingContext2DSettings
  ): CanvasRenderingContext2D | null
  getContext(
    contextId: 'webgl' | 'experimental-webgl', attributes?: WebGLContextAttributes
  ): WebGLRenderingContext | null
  getContext(
    contextId: 'webgl2', attributes?: WebGLContextAttributes
  ): WebGL2RenderingContext | null
}
```

Now, the problem is that we need to match incoming arguments with the correct attributes and callbacks. You can use a union of tuples as the type of your arguments, but for that to work you need to first, always reference individual argument by their index instead of destructuring (TS people are discussing fixing this) and secondly you have to have discriminator (i.e. type) on the top level:

```
function useCanvas(
  ...args:
    [
      '2d',
      (context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => void,
      CanvasRenderingContext2DSettings?
    ] |
    [
      'webgl' | 'experimental-webgl',
      (context: WebGLRenderingContext) => void,
      WebGLContextAttributes?
    ] |
    [
      'webgl2',
      (context: WebGL2RenderingContext) => void,
      WebGLContextAttributes?
    ]
): React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement> {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current !== null) {
      switch (args[0]) {
        case 'webgl': // fall-through
        case 'experimental-webgl': {
          const type = args[0];
          const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext(type, args[2]);
          ctx && args[1](ctx);
          break;
        }
        case 'webgl2': {
          const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext(args[0], args[2]);
          ctx && args[1](ctx);
          break;
        }
        default: {
          const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d', args[2]);
          ctx && args[1](ctx);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return canvasRef;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that does make sense. Unfortunately, if I try your solution (which is then just the union of the call signatures themselves, if I understand correctly), it still gives me an error:

`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => void) | ((context: WebGL2RenderingContext) => void) | ((context: WebGLRenderingContext) => void)' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: @cymin You can make your implmentation use `draw: (context: any) => void`, which will *not* expose `context: any` as a call signature, then use type-guards in your implementation to safely figure out what kind of context it is (the same you would do if your original syntax actually worked).

Comment: @Aaron I do not think, that this is exactly what I want. The usage of the function should just be `useCallback(thisIsA2dContext => {...})` or `useCallback(thisIsA2dContext => {...}, { type: '2d', ... )` or `useCallback(thisIsAWebGLContext => {...}, { type: 'webgl', ... )`. So from the function call, I can at compile time say, what type the callback's argument will be of.

Since I just use the getContext method of the canvas element, this will return either null or the specified context. If I check for the context not being null, I should be able to invoke the callback then, right?

Comment: So what I hope to achieve is, that when `useCanvas` is invoked, one can not accidentially pass a callback function which expects a wrong context type and invokes methods, that would not be available on the context, that is provided from `useCanvas` (specified by the second argument, defaulting to '2d').

Comment: @cymin I've updated the solution—should be callable now, and as I mentioned they should address this exact issue in TypeScript 3.3: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2019/01/23/announcing-typescript-3-3-rc/

Comment: @Grassator, this solution still does not work, two errors:

1. `Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.`
2. `Argument of type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | WebGLRenderingContext | WebGL2RenderingContext' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WebGL2RenderingContext'.
  Type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D' is missing the following properties from type 'WebGL2RenderingContext': ...`

I believe the solution @Aaron provided is the only way so far (TypeScript 3.3 will also only give intersections of arguments, not union). In this case, an explicit `any` seems appropriate.